# How to put a covariate into the linear-mixed effects model?

Tags: r, lme4

In my linear-fixed effect model, I have two fixed factors "Fix-1" and "Fix-2", and a random factor "Ran". I think the continuous factor "Cov" may influence the dependent, and this influence is mainly works on "Fix-1". Now my R code of this model is:

```
Dependent ~ Fix-1 * Fix-2 + (1 + Fix-1 + Fix-2|Ran)
```

How can I put the covariate "Cov"?

Comment: If you're saying that it's multicolinear then use an instrumental variable. 2SLS.

Comment: it's not really clear what you're asking, but if you simply want to add a covariate `Cov` to the model  you would just use `Dependent ~ Fix1*Fix2 +Cov + (1+Fix1+Fix2|Ran)`.  I think we need more context though.

Comment: @BenBolker Hi! Thanks for you reply. What I mean is that the Cov and Fix1 will combined act on the Dependent. Think about this case: Dependent is Weight, Fix1 is Health (e.g., adipose and non-adipose), Fix2 is, say, Nationality. The covariate is height. If i assume that for the non-adipose subjects, the higher the heavier, while for the adipose the height doesn't affect their weight. The Nationality does not influence the Weight as well. How can I improve this equation?